# What is the code of this square symbol?

Tags: symbols

Recently, I encounter this square symbol. Although I search carefully on the Internet, I could not figure out its syntax.

> [image]

Please help me find its syntax!

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\ding{114}
\end{document}`

Comment: `\SquareShadowB` using `ifsym` package

Comment: You can make it as macro for reusing in LaTex documentation `\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,thick,blue]
\def\a{1}
\filldraw (0,0)--(\a,0)--(\a,\a)
--++(-45:.2*\a)--++(-90:\a)--++(180:\a)--cycle;
\draw (0,0) rectangle (\a,\a);
\end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Zapf Dingbats through the `pifont` package features.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\unnamedsymbol}{\ding{113}}

\begin{document}

\unnamedsymbol

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a similar one at slot 111

[image]

If you want to use it as a math symbol, here analogous to the Alembertian,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\unnamedsymbol}{\mathop{{}\mathding{113}}\nolimits}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathding}[1]{\mathpalette\math@ding{#1}}
\newcommand{\math@ding}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \mbox{\normalfont\fontsize{%
    \ifx#1\displaystyle\f@size\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\f@size\else
    \ifx#1\scriptstyle\sf@size\else
    \ssf@size\fi\fi\fi}{0}\selectfont
    \ding{#2}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\unnamedsymbol F_{\unnamedsymbol F}$

\end{document}
```

[image]